# How can I use lists in an equation?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 3 lists:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np
a_x = list(range(0, 100))
T = list(range(100, 200))
p = np.tile(np.array([1000, 925, 850, 700, 500]), 20)
```

and I have an equation:

```
result = a_x * (p/(R*T))
```

Each list is of length 100. I could loop from 0 to 100 and use the index to access the items in the lists and pass them to the equation, but I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this.

How could I write my function such that I can pass in the 3 lists and have a list of tuples returned where index 0 of the tuple is an ID and index 1 is the value computed from the equation?

EG:

```
# a_x, T and p are lists, R is a constant
def compute(id, a_x, T, p):
    R = 0.2342344 #whatever
    return id, a_x * (p/(R*T))
```

Which would result in something like this:

```
> [(1, 0.213123), (2, 0.35635654), (3, 0.745345), (n, m)]
```

Comment: From a math standpoint, what you're asking is unclear.  Are you treating your lists as vectors?  If so, what does vector division mean in your world, and do you mean a dot product or a cross product?  Or are you wanting the first element of each list to interact with the first element of the other lists and produce the first element of a result?  That's not normally how math on arrays/lists/vectors works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` is good for this.

```
result = []
for a, b, c, d in zip(ids, a_x, T, p)):
    result.append(compute(a, b, c, d))
# where `ids` is the list of `id` numbers to pass to compute.
```

This can also be done as a list comprehension, and since `compute` is so straightforward, we can in-line it.

```
R = 0.2342344
result = [(id, a * (c/(R*b))) for id, a, b, c in zip(ids, a_x, T, p)]
```

Comment: Excellent. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension to accomplish this.

Given lists `a_x`, `T`, `p`, you need to iterate over 0 through 100, neatly.

```
[ ( id , a_x[id] * (p[id] / (R * T[id]) ) for id in range(100) ]
```

The list comprehension can map a list (the list of numbers from 0 - 99) to anything you want.. in this case a tuple of the value in the original list and your evaluated formula.

Comment: The ID is not the index, it is a separate list of numbers not part of the equation ;)

Comment: @pookie thanks for that -- I didn't realize that either.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
def compute_list(al, bl, cl):
    return [(i, compute(a,b,c)) for i, (a,b,c) in enumerate(zip(al,bl,cl))]

compute_list(a_x, T, p)
r = compute_list(a_x, T, p)
```

It returns a list of tuples.

Comment: Missing the IDs there ;)

Comment: enumerate generates IDs from 0 to 99 based on the zipped lists, doesn't it?

Comment: Indeed, it does, but I am supplying my own list of IDs.